# Run another binary/exe file using Lua?

Tags: lua, binary, arguments, exe

Quick question, lua code that will run a binary/exe file with arguments

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
os.execute('command with args')
```

is what you want.

Have a look at this [small tutorial](http://lua-users.org/wiki/OsLibraryTutorial).

PS: I found this after searching for around 10 seconds. I bet writing this question here took you longer...

Comment: You can also try [`io.popen`](http://pgl.yoyo.org/luai/i/io.popen) which you can use to read/write to the program you're running.

Comment: both os.execute and io.popen run an executable within the same process scope - so it doesnt launch a _seperate_ exe in a separate process from your running one (its expecting you to return from your called exe).